# How to run Vert.x Verticle on eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, vert.x

Can you list steps on how to run Vertical from eclipse or direct me to a source? I can't find clear steps anywhere on how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Run a Verticle from Eclipse With/Without external configuration file.**

I did this with HttpServer deployed using a verticle , but for simplicity I am taking a simple Verticle. If you don't want to pass config, just remove the -conf parameter from the command given below.

Lets say I have a class called SimpleVerticle.java

My project structure is like this.

[image]

My verticle code is as below.

```
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;

public class SimpleVerticle extends AbstractVerticle{


    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("In Simple Verticle Start Method");

        System.out.println("the port configuration is : "+config().getInteger("http.port",8080));
    }
}
```

My Config file looks like this :

```
{
  "http.port" : 8082
}
```

Now all you have to do is, 
Step1: right click on the verticle file , select RunAs -> Run Configurations
Step2: In the main tab, 
In the Main Class field,  enter `io.vertx.core.Launcher`

Step3: In the Arguments Tab,  in the Program Arguments  field, enter the below,

```
run com.tutorial.venu.SimpleVerticle -conf src/main/conf/vertx-myapp-conf.json
```

[image]
[image]

And click Run !!

Boom, you get your Verticle deployed with the configuration items taken from config file.

[image]

Please refer to the video link : 
http://vertx.io/blog/automatic-redeployment-in-eclipse-ide/

Answer (score 1):

Create and build the project using the maven archetype as explained here: http://vertx.io/maven_dev.html#generate-the-project

E.g., Using the following maven command: mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=io.vertx: -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=my-module -Dversion=0.1

1. Import the maven project into Eclipse
2. Create a Run Configuration of type Java Application
3. In Main tab enter Main Class: 
          org.vertx.java.platform.impl.cli.Starter
4. In Arguments tab enter Program arguments: 
          runmod com.mycompany~my-module~0.1
5. Click run.

Reference: http://www.smartjava.org/content/create-simpe-restful-service-vertx-20-rxjava-and-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is the Vert.x Google Group:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/vertx

There, you can get answers from Tim Fox and other core developers.

As for your Eclipse issue, I assume you found that page:

http://vertx.io/dev_guide.html